# How to fix UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d : character maps to <undefined>?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, unicode, utf-8

I am using `curl` to data.

```
import os
cmd = "curl --data \"action=getdata\" https:localhost:8070"
print(cmd)
data = os.popen(cmd).read()
```

The line above produces an error `UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 565334: character maps to <undefined>`.

When I debugged using breakpoints, the command `os.popen` generates a large corpus of text and when it goes to `read()` the error arises in file `cp1252.py` in `IncrementalDecoder` class. I tried doing,

```
data = os.popen(cmd).read().encode('utf-8').decode('ascii')
```

and

```
data = os.popen(cmd).read().encode().decode('utf-8')
```

But the error persists. How can we solve this?

Comment: It looks like `popen.read` will decode from bytes to a string, but I don't know if `curl` gives you a consistent encoding.  You may need to find another way.

Comment: Use [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) instead of `os.popen` if you need control over the encoding of the returned stream.